# Overlapping paragraph

Tags: sections-paragraphs, overlap

I have to say i have no idea what is happening here, the "test" should be below section 2 and not section 2.1 plus the overlapping subsection 2.2.
If i write a shorter definition then it works fine.
Any idea ?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: please always post code as a small complete document that can be run to debug the issue, it is virtually impossible to debug from a screenshot. But you should never have `\noindent` at the start of a section, does the issue go if you remove that?

Comment: apart from the overprinting subsection you seem to have excessive indent for `test` after the section, so presumably your heading definitions are incorrect but you have not shown them.